# Excel 2010 - explodes after trying to refresh odbc

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2013

I made a excel spreadsheet using office 2013 and it works fine. But when i try to open it in office 2010 it will crash when retrieving data.

**My configuration**: office 2013 - x64

**Client**: office 2010 - x32

**data source**: odbc

I have no clue what is wrong,

what have i tried:

if i do click on edit query and run the query it runs but as soon as i hit the button to take the data back to office it will just crash.

Comment: What file type have you saved it as? Is that one downwards compatible? Can you save it as 2010 version? Will that give incompatibility messages?

Comment: @K_B sorry for the late response. The file is xlsm, when office 2010 crashes i didn't notice that it gave me a (repaired) version, the file is the same, the conections are the same, the file size is the same, i have no idea what changes but it stop crashing after that. I thought that file was going to be compatible so forth, but then again after some modification even it ran on that computer and another computer with office 2013, when another computer with office 2010 open it, it crashed again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing powerpivot for office 2010?

This may give you a cleaner and more powerful solution, adaptable in both versions of Excel

Comment: No i havent, the thing is that this file is to be used among a whole network, adding something to office just for this report is not something i would like.